# Comparing two sas datasets

Tags: sas

I have two sas datasets

An answer dataset

```
id   A1 A2 A3 A4  
1    A  B  C  D
2    B  B  C  A
3    A  A  D  D
```

And a key dataset

```
A1 A2 A3 A4
A  B  C  D
```

The question is if there is a way in SAS to loop trough the observations in the first dataset and compare them with the only observation in the second dataset. I am quite new to SAS, so anything would be of help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looping is handled by the data step - it does that automatically.

To get a single row appended to all rows in another dataset is very simple:

```
data want;
  if _n_=1 then set have_onerow;
  set have;
run;
```

That only works if the variable names are different though - but that would append that row from have_onerow to all rows of have (as variables from SET are automatically retained).

This doesn't do the compare for you - you have to do that.

However, there's a way to use this to generate a `proc compare` dataset.    Keep only the ID and do the above: then you have the key repeated once per ID.  Then `proc compare` will do this for you - look at [the documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/65145/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0c1y14wyd3u7yn1dmfcpaejllsn.htm) to get more information on what options give you the right info in your output dataset.

```
data have;
input id   A1 $ A2 $ A3 $ A4 $ ;
datalines;
1    A  B  C  D
2    B  B  C  A
3    A  A  D  D
;;;;
run;

data key;
input a1 $ a2 $ a3 $ a4 $;
datalines;
A B C D
;;;;
run;

data key_allrows;
  if _n_=1 then set key;
  set have (keep=id);
run;

proc compare base=key_allrows compare=have out=compare;
  by id;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you! But can I use the result of this comparison to form a new dataset? For example: if the number of inequalities for id exceeds 2 put this observation into the dataset "failure"

Comment: Yep.  Look at the documentation; it covers a lot of different options.  The above should produce a third 'compare' dataset, which just has '........' if they're identical or 'X.......' if they're not (because they are 8 character long the way I lazily input them).  You have a lot of options that control this.  Feel free to ask another question if you have something specific to proc compare once you've tried this, if it's sufficiently different from this question!

Answer (score 1):

```
proc sort data=a; by a1 a2 a3 a4; run;
proc sort data=b; by a1 a2 a3 a4; run;

data c;
  merge a(in=ina) b(in=inb)
  by a1 a2 a3 a4;
  if inb then b='Ý';
run;
```

it creates data set a with indicator b='Ý' for the matching one